# Postgres SQL : rows to name, value json pairs

Tags: postgresql

Given a row with Col1, Col2. How to convert the row into

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Col1",
        "value": "Column1Value"
    },
    {
        "name": "Col2",
        "value": "Column2Value"
    }
]
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scalar subselect:

```
select (select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('name', key, 'value', value))
        from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(d)) as j)
from the_table d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Substitute `the_table` with your actual table name.

```sql
with jsonrows(jsonobject, rownumber) as 
(
    select to_json(t), row_number() over () 
    from the_table t
)
select json_agg(json_build_object('name', key, 'value', value))
from jsonrows 
cross join lateral json_each_text(jsonobject) 
group by rownumber;
```

Comment: The solution of @a_horse_with_no_name is better I think ...